# Redirect Virtual Host Before SSL Termination

Tags: apache, ssl

I own two domains, exampleA.com and exampleB.com. We have migrated to example B completely, and all traffic to exampleA.com is redirected to exampleB.com. We have SSL enabled in both sites, and our certificate for exampleA.com has expired. I thought I had configured apache to redirect to exampleB.com before SSL termination in all scenarios, but that is not the case the URL is of the form:

- https://exampleA.com
- https://www.exampleA.com

In browsers we are now receiving "not a private connection" errors, but when using postman to call the URL I get the proper redirects. I'm not sure what is causing this mismatch, I'm guessing the browsers are being more strict.

Here is my existing redirect in apache, which worked before the existing certificate expired:

```
#EXAMPLEA.COM HTTPS 443
<VirtualHost *:443>
  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs"
  SSLEngine on
  ServerName exampleA.com
  ServerAlias www.exampleA.com
  RedirectPermanent / https://www.exampleB.com/
SSLCertificateFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.key"
SSLCACertificateFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server-ca.crt"

  <Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    <IfVersion < 2.3 >
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.3 >
      Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
  </Directory>

  # Error Documents
  ErrorDocument 503 /503.html

  # Bitnami applications installed with a prefix URL (default)
  Include "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf"
</VirtualHost>
```

Obviously the expired certificate is still referenced in this configuration. I tried to remove it but apache would not start.

I've tried reading the apache documentation and I can't see a way to redirect SSL traffic without actually having a valid certificate installed.

My alternative would be to redirect at the domain level, but I'm not sure if this would preserve paths to resources the way an apache redirect will.

To summarise my question, is it possible to do this redirection in apache while not owning a valid certificate for the old domain?

Comment: "I thought I had configured apache to redirect to exampleB.com before SSL termination" This is not possible as an HTTP redirection can only occur at the HTTP level which is "after" TLS level, so the webserver first needs to complete the TLS handshake, then it can get the `Host` header from the client to know which website it wants, on which it can reply with a `Location` header to do an HTTP redirection.

Comment: Please do not use `exampleA.com` and `exampleB.com` as examples, as they are not. From RFC2606 you can find guidance, that is either `example.com` + `example.net` or using any domain name in the `.example` TLD.